# Android: Register/Creating ContextMenu for CalendarView

Tags: android, android-calendar

how do you use contextmenu on calendar view, becuase when i registered the CalendarView for context, i have to long click the whole view, i jsut want to long click dates not the whole view and show contextmenu.

how am i going to register contextmenus on calendarview?.